# Question on 90V DC motors

Tags: dc-motor

Back then, 90V dc motors were controlled by SCRs. Nowadays, some of them are PWM-controlled as happen in treadmills. Basically my question is:
120VAC rectified and filtered are about 170VDC (It's what I normally see in these boards). For a 90VDC motor, this is too much. The idea on this is controlling the duty cycle under 50%?

Comment: Basically that's what digital servo do: use pwm to control a motor. So yes, pwm would go below 50% in this case, a very common situation.

Comment: A treadwheel tach is needed if driving variable Vdc for servo speed control.  high voltage IGBT's may be necessary and  series Choke rated for current to reduce ripple current. Switching at higher speeds with a load cap is not basically a buck converter.  But smaller AC motors with VFD drivers have better performance and constant Vac/f and flatter torque range now.  But if you have the motors already, its cheaper to buy than make https://www.amazon.ca/24V-90V-Controller-Electric-Regulator-Permanent/dp/B076KPP92X/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1532203786&sr=8-3&keywords=90v+dc+motor